# call from command line, show file also if the search does not match

Tags: vim, command-line, arguments

I use a msdos-script to search with vim for patterns and show me the result

#### Script: tel.bat

```
rem script is called: tel.bat <pattern>
gvim -R %WORKSPACE%\telliste.csv "+set ignorecase" "+set ft=javascript" -c /%1
```

This works fine if the pattern exist in the file. If the pattern is not matched, I get an error message and I am stuck. No keystroke or mouse action changes the state. Like:

```
Enter key - has no effect
Esc key   - has no effect
Ctrl + C  - the error-messages disappears, but the editor is frozen. No action possible
Mouse click in editor - has no effect
```

I can only close vim and try again. That's what I get as error, when I call the script `tel.bat konez` on the command line:

[image: vim error message]

Error message translated:

```
Error during execution of "command line": 
E486: Pattern not found: konez
Confirm with the ENTER Key or place a command
```

**How can I work further on the file, even if the pattern is not found?** In other words how can I avoid that I am stuck in vim.

I tried already with `-c ":execute 'silent !'"` in the batch file, but this was not recognized. Perhaps I did it in the wrong way...

Comment: can you change the batch file? what is in it? can't you return to vim with enter?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Yes, I can change; Content is stated, see the first code-description; Correct, I can't return to vim by hitting enter.

Comment: hmm.. this might help: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8704/dont-fail-if-pattern-is-not-found but no idea why you can't continue with enter.

Comment: I found out that hitting ``Ctrl + C`` has an effect, the messages at the _commando mode_ disapear and the _insert mode_ seems to be entered, but in the _insert mode_ the editor is frozen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* work, and I cannot reproduce this on Linux with Vim version 8.0.1358; I can accept the error message with `<Enter>` and continue.

This could be a plugin / configuration issue; try launching with `gvim --clean`.

The multi-line error message is ugly. You could avoid it by moving to the lower-level `search()` function:

```
gvim ... -c "call search('%1')"
```

By evaluating its return value; you could also craft your own error message: `if search(...) == 0 | echomsg 'No matches' | endif`